# How can I stop my image from being pushed to the left within a flex container when the text length increases?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a logo and text aligned in the center of the page and when the text's length increases, the logo is pushed leftwards. I've tried so many things but cannot figure out how to fix this.

[image]

here is my HTML

```
<div class="app">
  <div class="root">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a"></img>
      <div class="text">
      <span class="title">Stack Overflow</span>
      <span class="subtitle">Some More text 
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and my CSS

```
html, body {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: SlateGrey
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.app {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.root {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

 .container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center
}

.text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.title {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.subtitle: {
  fontSize: 13px;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

**Codepen**: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LBYozL

Add more text to the span with class `subtitle` to see what I mean

Comment: That's kind of how centering works? Are you saying you want the text to wrap?

Comment: I would like the text and logo centered in the middle of the page and to be "static" in the sense that it doesn't re-adjust its position when the length of the subtitle text increases if that makes any sense?

Comment: see my answer, you probably want to set `flex-shrink` and `flex-grow`. I did it in a one liners which is `flex: <flex-grow> <flex-shrink> <flex-basis>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the image in a div.
Set the container and its immediate descendants `flex` (flex-grow, flex-shrink-, flex-basis) property.
Set text-align.
Change spans to div so they display block.
Remove invalid css.

```css
html, body {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: SlateGrey
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.app {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.root {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}

.image {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  text-align: right;
}

.text {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-align: left
}

.title {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  flex: 0 0 100%
}

.subtitle: {
  fontSize: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="root">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a"/>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <div class="title">Stack Overflow</div>
        <div class="subtitle">Some text...adadgadgfsdfgsdfg</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your `.text` container a hardcoded width, and then the text will wrap instead of pushing the logo out of center, so for example

```
.text {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   margin-left: 20px;
   width: 150px; // Set this to what ever you want but this looks how you had it
}
```

or you could set a max-width...

```
.text {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   margin-left: 20px;
   max-width: 200px; // this will never go over 200px
}
```

but setting a definite width will keep everything positioned exactly how you like it.

for example

```css
html, body {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: SlateGrey
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.app {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.root {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}

.text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 150px;
}

.title {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.subtitle: {
  fontSize: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="root">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a"></img>
    <div class="text">
      <span class="title">Stack Overflow really really long text lol</span>
      <span class="subtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu impedit epicuri phaedrum has. Vel id probo definitionem, alia justo labores at vel. Usu dolor quodsi scaevola at, tamquam quaestio honestatis sea id, ponderum splendide qui ut. Vix ignota vivendo denique id</span>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No really only one way, you answered about `width` then I showed him about `max-width`, them you copy it https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51275525/revisions, anyway, we are trying to help.

Comment: I answered first, then on reflection I stated he could also use max-width, these are two very basic properties of css, I was in the process of editing my question before I even saw yours

Answer (score 1):

You can simply limit the `.text` div width by using `max-width` to the size you would like to limit it, them it would be responsive as well.

```
.text {
  ...
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: SlateGrey
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.app {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.root {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}

.text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 20px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.title {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.subtitle: {
  fontSize: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="root">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a"></img>
    <div class="text">
      <span class="title">Stack Overflow really really long text lol</span>
      <span class="subtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu impedit epicuri phaedrum has. Vel id probo definitionem, alia justo labores at vel. Usu dolor quodsi scaevola at, tamquam quaestio honestatis sea id, ponderum splendide qui ut. Vix ignota vivendo denique id, in mel mediocrem incorrupte. At purto latine adolescens has.</span>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```